# Installing packages, not working (update)

Tags: python, package

I need terminaltables, a package in python, for an assignment in school, the problem is, I can for some reason not make it work, I've installed pip, it's working and I can call pip help. I've used the commandoes: sudo pip install terminaltables and pip install terminaltables. After looking it up, my version of pip is 2.7 and python is 2.7.6, terminaltables is 3.0.0. I'm trying to use terminaltables with this code, notice that this is only example code copied:

```
from terminaltables import AsciiTable
table_data = [
    ['Heading1', 'Heading2'],
    ['row1 column1', 'row1 column2'],
    ['row2 column1', 'row2 column2'],
    ['row3 column1', 'row3 column2']
]
table = AsciiTable(table_data)
print(table.table)
```

When I try to run this, I type python3 yatzy4.py (yatzy4 is the name of my file). It says that there is no module named "terminaltables". I'm not a good programmer, I'm trying to learn, I'm unsure of what I should do. I checked some other posts here on stackoverflow and there were discussion of paths.

I'm unsure how my path should look like and how do I check this? Been stuck with this problem since earlier this day, and it seems like I can't figure it out myself. I'm probably gonna get downvoted and banned from writing again, but it drives me nuts that it simply wont work, I hope that someone, who might have had the same issue, can help me and hopefully others. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running your file in Python 3, but you installed `terminaltables` for Python 2.

Either use Python 2 (`python yatzy4.py`) or install `terminaltables` for Python 3 (Probably `pip3 install terminaltables`, depending on your setup.)

Comment: thank god for your help Kyle! Its working, its finally working, im so grateful right now! Thanks for saving my day